# Cannot see primefaces components in visual tab of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, primefaces

I am developing a Dynamic Web Project with Eclipse Indigo SR2. I am using Primefaces 3.4.2 and, when editing the .xhtml, the `Visual` view does not show the components properly.

[image]

I am using JBossTools and deploying to a JBoss server; I have tried adding the primefaces library both to the web-inf/lib or as a user library, but to no avail.

Google finds few results for this, most of the issues are with getting autocompletion to work (which it does correctly, btw).

Is there a way to show the visual components? I am not sure if maybe I am expecting too much, but it was a neat feature when using richfaces components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way, use a real browser to preview as JSF views are hot deployed on the fly.

Comment: I take it you can be considered a well informed source. Thank you.