# PrimeFaces components does not show up in the eclipse kepler palette

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, eclipse-kepler

I added the primefaces.jar in to the classpath of the javaserver faces project. But in the web page editor palette the primefaces tab is empty!.
[image: empty primefaces tab]

The JSF HTML tabs are full with standard JSF components. As shown below!
[image: JSF HTML tab is full]

I checked this question as well: [Cannot see primefaces components in visual tab of eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841769/cannot-see-primefaces-components-in-visual-tab-of-eclipse).
I really can get why the web editor does not preview the PrimeFaces components, since they are "hot deployed on the fly" as mentioned in the linked question. But shouldn't the components be visible in the palette so we could add them by drag & drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK! after I restarted the machine the menu had two tabs for the PrimeFaces UI and Mobile . I don't know why I had to restart the machine? It didn't work when I restarted eclipse.

[image: PrimeFace UI components available in the palette]